# How do I change the background color in the undecorated frame?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I have an undecorated frame and I want to change the background color for it.  How to do that?

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share a reason?  IMWTK.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson any reason(s) short question, short answer, both +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: @Mikel, See also: [Using Top-Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).